# Sending Video Stream from Next.js Front-end to FastAPI Backend and Displaying with OpenCV

Tags: javascript, next.js, websocket, streaming, fastapi

I'm working on an application that requires video streaming capabilities. I have a front-end built with Next.js and a back-end implemented using FastAPI. Additionally, I want to process and display this video stream using OpenCV.

This is the code for the back with FastAPI and python, it simply receives the data with a websocket and open the frames with openCV:

```
@app.websocket("/ws")
async def websocket_endpoint(websocket: WebSocket):
    await websocket.accept()
    try:
        while True:
            data = await websocket.receive_bytes()
            nparr = np.frombuffer(data, np.uint8)
            frame = cv.imdecode(nparr, cv.IMREAD_COLOR)

            if frame is not None:
                # Your OpenCV processing logic here
                cv.imshow("frame", frame)
                cv.waitKey(1)

    except WebSocketDisconnect:
        print("WebSocket disconnected")
        cv.destroyAllWindows()
        await websocket.close()
```

For the front, the main logic to send the video is in the `startCamera` function:

```
import React, { useRef, useEffect, useState } from 'react';
import { Button, Card, Row} from 'antd';

const Webcam = () => {
  const videoRef = useRef(null);
  const mediaStreamRef = useRef(null);
  const mediaRecorderRef = useRef(null);
  const websocket = useRef(null);

  const startCamera = async () => {
    try {
      const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({ video: true });
      mediaStreamRef.current = stream;
      videoRef.current.srcObject = stream;
      videoRef.current.play();

      // Crear conexion WebSocket 
      websocket.current = new WebSocket('ws://localhost:3010/ws');

      websocket.current.onopen = () => {
        console.log('WebSocket connected');
      };

      mediaRecorderRef.current = new MediaRecorder(stream);

      mediaRecorderRef.current.ondataavailable = (e) => {
        if (e.data.size > 0) {
          websocket.current.send(e.data); // Mandar video por websocket
        }
      };

      mediaRecorderRef.current.start(1000); // Empezar recording the cada segundo

    } catch (error) {
      console.error('Error obtaining camera stream: ', error);
    }
  };

  const stopCamera = () => {
    if (mediaStreamRef.current) {
      const tracks = mediaStreamRef.current.getTracks();
      tracks.forEach((track) => {
        track.stop();
      });
      mediaStreamRef.current = null; 
      videoRef.current.srcObject = null;
    }

    if (websocket.current) {
      websocket.current.close();
    }

    if (mediaRecorderRef.current) {
      mediaRecorderRef.current.stop();
    }
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    return () => {
      stopCamera();
    };
  }, []);

  return (
    <Card title="Stream">
      <video
        ref={videoRef}
        style={{ width: '100%', height: 'auto' }}
        autoPlay
        playsInline
        muted
      />
       <Row justify="center" style={{ marginTop: 'auto' }}>
        <Button
          type="primary"
          onClick={() => startCamera()}
          style={{ margin: '1rem' }}
        >
          Comenzar Sesión
        </Button>
        <Button style={{ margin: '1rem' }} 
                type="danger" 
                onClick={() => stopCamera()}>
          Terminar Sesión
        </Button>
      </Row>
    </Card>
  );
};

export default Webcam;
```

While it does connect and sends the data, the `frame` variable always gets assigned None. Im not sure exactly whats wrong with it.

Comment: you can't mix web servers with desktop GUI. -- problem requires further debugging. figure out what you're actually receiving. figure out if that's a valid image. dump the data to a file. no decoding. just dumping.